# Handle image file and save it to media

Tags: media, media-library, uploads

I have function that gets uploaded file, save it, then crop it with `imagecrop` and now I need to save it again to the media. I know the way, how to do that with vanilla `PHP`, but I need file to be inserted (meta data) to the database, not only save the file to the server.

With this function, I am inserting the file to the media:

```
$attachmentId = media_handle_upload('image', 0);
```

Then I am getting file path:

```
$img= get_attached_file($attachmentId);
```

Then I am using a custom for cropping the image:

```
function crop($filePath, $cropWidth, $cropHeight, $cropX, $cropY){

    // returns imageCreateFromJpeg($filepath), 
    $image = $this->createImageFromAnyType($filepath); 

    $cropped = imagecrop($image, ['x' => $cropX, 
                       'y' => $cropY, 'width' => $cropWidth, 'height' => $cropHeight]);

    return $cropped ? imagejpeg($cropped) : false;
}
```

Now I have this resource `imagejpeg($cropped)` which I don't know how to save, similar as `media_handle_upload`.

Comment: Shouldn't you be cropping it before uploading? `media_handle_upload()` creates the attachment and inserts the information into the database. Your code is modifying an image that's already been uploaded to the media library.

Comment: No cropping before upload, but I think the logic will be same. I need to upload it with `media_handle_upload`, then crop it and save it again as another image. At the end , there are two images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was to get media folder and save there the cropped image. After that update meta data:

```
$imageToCropPath= get_attached_file($attachmentId); // Get file path to the image that will be cropped
$img = imageCreateFromJpeg($imageToCropPath);

$croppedImage = imagecrop($img, ['x' => $cropX, 
                                 'y' => $cropY, 
                                 'width' => $cropWidth, 
                                 'height' => $cropHeight]);

$uniqueId = md5(uniqid()); // Create unique name for the new image

$imagePath = wp_upload_dir()['path'] . '/' . $uniqueId . '.jpg';
imagejpeg($croppedImage,  $imagePath); // Save image in the media folder

$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => 'image/jpeg',
    'post_title' => basename($imagePath),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
);

$croppedAttachmentId = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $imagePath );

$attachedData = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $croppedAttachmentId, $imagePath);

wp_update_attachment_metadata( $croppedAttachmentId , $attachedData );
```